# Typo3 6.0 - load form fields depending on type of News 2.1

Tags: forms, types, load, typo3, tx-news

I am new to Typo3, I'm using version 6.0. 
I have made a custom extension extending from News 2.1, and I made some custom fields and created a new type of news called "Activity". What I want to do is that when you choose "Activity" from the select type, the form reloads with the custom fields I want.

In other words, I want to reproduce what happens when you change the type of new from "News" to "Internal page" for example, but with the fields I want like in this : (in ext_tables.php)

```
$tmp_activite_columns = array(

'act_field1' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:myExt.act_field1',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 30,
        'eval' => 'trim'
    ),
),
'act_axe' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:myExt.act_axe',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 30,
        'eval' => 'trim'
    ),
),
);
```

How can I use `$tmp_activite_columns` so the form loads with these fields ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add this columns permanently to your TCA. Via TCA, you can then define a `displayCond` (display condition) to fields you only want to display, if another field has a certain value.

I assume your form already reloads when you choose the type, so here is an example for the `displayCond` in the TCA:

```
'act_field1' => array(
  'displayCond' => 'FIELD:type:=:3',
  'exclude' => 0,
  'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myExt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:myExt.act_field1',
  'config' => array(
    'type' => 'input',
    'size' => 30,
    'eval' => 'trim'
   ),
),
```

So basically you check if the field "type" has the value "3" for example. You can find more information about `displayCond` in the [TCA Documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Index.html).

Comment: I didn't know of displayCond, this is going to help me a lot, thank you!